# Iterate over a dict except for x item items

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict in this format:

```
d_data = {'key_1':value_1,'key_2':value_2,'key_3':value_3,'key_x':value_x,'key_n':value_n}
```

and I have to iterate over it's items:

```
for key,value in columns.items():
    do something
```

except for the pair:

```
'key_x':value_x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension or generator expression to filter:

```
for key,value in (i for i in columns.items() if not i==('key_x',value_x)):
    do something
```

Comment: Is it possible to filter only by **values** not by full specification value+key?

Comment: try `.values()`?

Comment: the syntax of IF will be `if not i==(value_x)`?

Answer (score 11):

Simply use the [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-continue-statement) statement, to skip ahead to the next iteration of the for loop:

```
for key,value in columns.items():
    if key == 'key_x':
        continue
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also iterate through the output of `filter` built-in method (which yields a generator in Python3+), this way:

```
>>> for x in filter('key_x'.__ne__, d_data):
        print(x, d_data[x])


key_3 value_3
key_n value_n
key_1 value_1
key_2 value_2
```

Comment: Aye, that was me.  `filter` + `lambda` is unpythonic, slow, and has been [explicitly discouraged by Guido](http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.ppt).  `filter('key_x'.__ne__, d_data)` is an equivalent alternative, or better yet just use comprehensions.

Comment: @wim...yea...I just grasped these days that they idea of combining `filter`, `map` or anything similar with `lambda` hits the performance down...thank you for the suggestion and code updated as well, now my question is, what's the appropriate places to use `__ne__` or similar methods?